# Django sort QuerySets

Tags: django

Hello iam making game administration website with django and i need help with sorting 2 queryes . These are my models.

```py
class Game(models.Model):
    game_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    stages = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    registration_start = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False)
    registration_end = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False)
    game_start = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False)
    game_end = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False)
    max_players = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    
class GameControl(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    game_name = models.ForeignKey(Game,
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    progress = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=0)
    game_time = models.DurationField(null=True, blank=True)
```

[models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfMYz.png)

and i need to separate from them registered game_names and unregistered game_names

```py
@login_required(login_url='/signin')
def home(request):
    current_user = request.user
    registered = GameControl.objects.filter(user=current_user)
    unregistered = Game.objects.all()
    
    return render(request, "games/home.html", {'unregistered': unregistered ,'registered': registered })
```

[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jva5.png)

I was trying to make this in template but it didnt work

```py
{% for un in unregistered %}
                {% if un.game_name  in registered.game_name %}
                    <button type="button" class="btn">{{un.game_name}} 
                    <i class="material-icons" style="float: 
                     right;">close</i></span></button>
                    <br>
                {% else %}
                    <button type="button" class="btn">{{un.game_name}} 
                    <i class="material-icons" style="float: 
                     right;">arrow_forward</i></span></button>
                    <br>
                {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

[template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwNxS.png)

Help Please <3.

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Comment: sorry my false, it should have run out to me right away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, in the view you should just create a list of registered game names:

```py
@login_required(login_url='/signin')
def home(request):
    current_user = request.user
    registered = GameControl.objects.filter(user=current_user)
    unregistered = Game.objects.all()
    
    return render(request, "games/home.html", {'unregistered': unregistered ,'registered_names': [reg.game_name for reg in registered] })
```

And then the template:

```html
{% for un in unregistered %}
                {% if un.game_name  in registered_names %}
                    <button type="button" class="btn">{{un.game_name}} 
                    <i class="material-icons" style="float: 
                     right;">close</i></span></button>
                    <br>
                {% else %}
                    <button type="button" class="btn">{{un.game_name}} 
                    <i class="material-icons" style="float: 
                     right;">arrow_forward</i></span></button>
                    <br>
                {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank for answer, but still not working , the condition  {% if un.game_name  in registered_names %} does not register any same game_mames in unregistered and registered_names.